# how to convert float and string into integer value in python3

Tags: python-3.x, integer

i have a value which is float and string (it's in quotation marks) and i have to convert a integer value.
for example ,when i write `x = "1.2"`, i want take this output:`1`

i wrote this code:

```
x = "1.2"
print(int(x))
```

but i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File xxx, line 2, in <module>
    print(int(x))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.2'
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: `print(int(float('1.2')))` - basically convert it a float (real number) first and then round it as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the string is going to be a float use `float(x)` to turn it in to a float first. Then you can use `int()` around that or if you need to round you can use another function like `round()` to round the number.

```
print(int(float(x))
```